# How to construct variable name in Bash?

Tags: bash, escaping, symbols

I want to construct variable name `N_foo` and `N_bar` and use their values in the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
N_foo=2
N_bar=3
for i in { "foo" "bar" }
do
    for j in { 1..$(`N_$i`) }
    do
        echo $j
    done
done
```

I want to use the values of `N_foo` and `N_bar` in the two inner loops and print out 1, 2 and 1, 2, 3, respectively. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: first youll have to remove the `{` `}` from outer for and remove space next to the `{}` in inner loop. `echo { 1..3 }` does not produce what you want.

Comment: arrays are the best way to avoid this kind of "eval" hell. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
N_foo=2
N_bar=3
for i in "foo" "bar"
do
    key="N_${i}"
    eval count='$'$key
    for j in `seq 1 $count`
    do
        echo $j
    done
done
```

Comment: `eval` is the classic solution to this sort of issue.

Comment: @Computist: I rejected the edit you made to this answer.  The answer didn't use the `${!symbol}` syntax you are asking about.  Your edit is really a new question.  If you decide not to open a new question for it, you should edit your own question instead of the answer.

Comment: Notice that you do not need the inner loop -- `seq 1 $count` is enough.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the indirect variable reference operator:

Example

```
var="foo"
nfoo=1
ref=n${var}
echo $ref
echo ${!ref}
```

Which gives this output:

```
nfoo
1
```

Comment: Ignacio: Yeah you're right - didn't work like I expected it to when used in the for loop range braces. {1..${!var}} didn't create a range like I thought it would....

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash
N_foo=2
N_bar=3
for i in "foo" "bar"
do
    i2="N_$i"
    seq 1 ${!i2}
done
```

Comment: Much better (and concise than the accepted answer). Thank you.

Comment: Not sure about "better" -- `seq` is nonportable, not specified by POSIX nor included as part of bash.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code. It uses the parameter substitution technique (c.f. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
N_foo=2
N_bar=3
for i in "foo" "bar"
do
j_max=N_$i
for (( j=1;  j<=${!j_max}; j++ ))
    do
    echo $j
    done
done
```

The `!` is history expansion parameter (c.f. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters). `!j_max` will be replaced by the most recent value set to `j_max` which is `N_foo`/`N_bar` in 1st/2nd iteration. It then calls `${N_foo}`/`${N_bar}` which has value 2/3 in the 1st/2nd iteration.

Comment: Please avoid linking to the ABS -- it's the W3Schools of bash, full of bad-practice examples and outdated content. Consider [the bash-hackers' wiki on indirection](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection), or [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).